# Remote monitoring system for CAPD

Tags: java, android, device

I know there are devices out there that monitors i.e. glucose of a CAPD patient. My question is do you know if I can read/access those data? I'm planning to create an Android app that read those data but I am hitting a wall as I dont know other devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can read data off many medical devices, BUT the interfaces differ and the communication protocols also differ, AND not all devices support outside data collection. You will have to go device by device and write a device driver for each.

Kind of like you PC printer. Can they communicate with PC? Of course they can - but some connect over USB, some over PS2, some over LAN, some over Wifi, AND almost all of them require a device driver to 'talk'.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I just found out about OpenYou. However as you said every device has a different communication protocol and that is tough.